# Best practices for creation of console for console based applications

Tags: java, console

To improve console application I have made I though adding some new functions to track for example the status of threads (these threads are responsible for monitoring data from different sources). So what I was thinking to do is create some kind of mechanism which would allow me to query the status of my application. The following methods are the methods I thought to implement:
1) Simple thread listening for user input and checking some variables or calling some functions on monitoring threads. Quite simple to implement, but has one problem at least I don't see the way to overpass it: application can run for monthes and if I want to access the machine where it is running using SSH it will be not possible to use my "console"
2) Create some RMI or some socket interface which could be connected by another simple program, sending commands and recieving responses. Seems to me the most suitable method, more hard to implement but can be quite powerfull.
3) The last and the simplest sulution, which is not console, but could serve my needs is writing data to some file and after reading the file. I don't cosider implementing this because it's not interactive at all.

The question is: is there any better method to implementing console for some java application besides the presented ones?

Thanks a lot,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is something similar to your ideas about RMI.  You could use a different technology if you like, but the idea of allowing the application to accept new monitoring connections is critical.

File base solutions (like you outline in #3) fall victim to loss of the file, lack of disk space, etc).  Solutions like you mention in #1 fall victim to not properly handling the access from a different user space.

With RMI (or similar, like CORBA, SOAP, Web Service, etc.) you get proper networking which allows people to communicate when on different machines (or just in different process spaces).  That's a lot of value (and a bit of code), but it is far less headache than a the job half-done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you are rejecting option 1.

These days its really easy to host a small web server to publish these kind of stats. Just run an embedded jetty instance with a small dashboard.

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, [JMX](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole?_sscc=t) beans give lots of these thread stats for free.

[CodaHale](https://github.com/codahale/metrics) is another solution with integrates with both JMX and tools like [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)

Comment: If you embed the details in a small web server, you typically have to run the program in an environment that suits a small web server.  Not terribly hard to do, but sometimes you want your program to not be restricted to the lock down that would be required to run a web server securely.  Other times, it's just too much port contention / configuration (if there is a plethora of small web servers).  Your solution is a good one, provided that it fits well in his environment.

Comment: +1 setting up a web server on java is almost easier than building a console/command line app.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: I don't see how RMI is any easier than jetty or tomcat.

Comment: @Kevin, Sometimes you need to do more than GET and POST.  In such cases, converting HTTP to a reasonable API can be more work than just exporting an RMI / CORBA / SOAP API.  Might not apply to your immediate problems, but at least it's an example of how RMI could be easier than Jetty or Tomcat.  And certain tasks, like asking a web server to initiate a connection (to yourself or another) isn't even possible without leaving the pure-HTTP protocol (RMI, CORBA, SOAP, etc).

Comment: @EdwinBuck Agreed on the security of web server issues. But if the purpose is to monitor threads there are a whole slew of tools to do that. Why make your own RMI solution? The out of the box JVM JMX beans give all the info about threads you normally need. A simple profiler with with a socket interface for remote connections gives even more detail.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail, you are right, JMX is yet another excellent tool.  And the best tool all depends on the requirements, which might not (yet) be fully fleshed out, and certainly have not been exposed to us.

Answer (score 0):

If by console you mean a console application (i.e. reads stdin and writes stdout), then you can try the linux command screen, which can create a virtual terminal that can be detached from the actual terminal. So it's possible for example to start your program in screen, detach, logout, ssh back a day later, attach to the prior screen session, and your problem is still running.

That said, I think running a war in tomcat/jetty with a monitoring page is a much better idea.